# jquery same function to div and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi have a script to toggle between languages dans a web. Acts on different elements over id or classes and works perfectly. Is exactly the same script, changing `('#' + block_name + '')` for id and `'.' + block_name + ''` for classes. Is there a way to simplify this in just one script?

Script 1:

```
var display = function(block_name, title) {
$('.CENTER').css('display', 'none');
$('#' + block_name + '').css('display', 'block');}

$('.UK').on('click', function() {display('LUK', $(this));
});

$('.ES').on('click', function() {
display('LES', $(this));
});

$('.FR').on('click', function() {
display('LFR', $(this));
});
```

Script 2:

```
var display = function(block_name, title) {
$('.info, .frames, .button').css('display', 'none');
$('.' + block_name + '').css('display', 'block');
}

$('.UK').on('click', function() {
display('LUK', $(this));
});

$('.ES').on('click', function() {
display('LES', $(this));
});

$('.FR').on('click', function() {
display('LFR', $(this));
});
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do it?

Comment: please provide html code

Comment: (Side note: The `+ ''` you have in various places is completely unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your `class` and 'id` selectors:

```
$("'.' + block_name, '#' + block_name").css('display', 'block');
```

See this [very simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/ygnxabvq/)

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuerys [.add-Function](https://api.jquery.com/add/) for this. $(".c1").add("#b1") to select both .c1 and #b1.

I don't understand why you need the second .on("click")-Bindings in your second script. If the first script is executed, then you won't need the second onclick handlers or you will end with two onclick eventhandlers for one element.